# layout-large-mdpi-land not working on Android 1.6?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've doubled checked that I'm targeting Android 1.6 , but layout-large-mdpi-land, layout-large-land, and layout-mdpi-land all show an 'invalid resource directory name:' error.

The weird thing is that layout-large-mdpi works just fine, and so does layout-land, but whenever I combine the land tag with another tag, suddenly eclipse yells at me. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if you are sticking to the norms given [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)